# Multiple quantities of an object that has a descriptor and units of measure

Tags: hyphenation, measuring-units

My question is probably best illustrated with an example:

> Four 2.25 hp electric motors were used to propel the vehicle.

Is that correct? I feel like it can't be, but my friend is saying otherwise. I'm also finding contradictory rules on the internet so I'm not sure. I think it should be:

> Four 2.25-hp electric motors were used to propel the vehicle.
>
> > or Four 2.25-hp-electric motors were used to propel the vehicle. ?

I know similar questions have been asked but they were simpler than mine. Hopefully someone can help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What you're saying is perfectly fine as it's clear that the electric motors are 2.25 hp each.

If you want to avoid confusion though, you could use the word "separate"

> Four separate 2.25 hp electric motors were used to propel the vehicle.

**[Separate](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/separate?s=t)**

> adjective
>
> 1. detached, disconnected, or disjoined.
> 2. unconnected; distinct; unique: two separate questions.
> 3. being or standing apart; distant or dispersed: two separate houses; The desert has widely separate oases.
> 4. existing or maintained independently: separate organizations.
> 5. individual or particular: each separate item.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any need for the dashes '`-`' to join `2.25` `hp` and `electric`, but because the unit for horsepower is lower case `hp` is does look a little clumsy.

It may be clearer is you spell out horsepower in full as `2.25 horsepower electric motor`

Depending on the layout of the vehicle and it's motors you could reword the sentence to

> The vehicle is/was propelled by a 2.25 horsepower electric motor at each
>   wheel.

then there is no issue with plurality either.

Comment: Yes, that's one of the functions of Passive -- to avoid such situations where the details don't matter. Note (1) that the focus -- the new information -- in the sentence continues to be the four two and a quarter horsepower motors, and (2) that the end of the sentence is as prominent a position for the focus as the beginning.